# Problem with generating signed certificate for docker when using extfile.cnf

Tags: docker, openssl, windows-10, certificate

I am trying to generate a signed certificate for docker using openssl, but I seem to be running into an error when trying to actually generate the signed certificate using the extfile.cnf

I am essentially following this guide:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket

When it comes to the step "Now, generate the signed certificate:"

I get the error: "x509: Error on line 1 of config file "extfile.cnf""

I am sure this is not docker specific or anything, and relates to openssl itself.

Can someone assist me here? thanks

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

Comment: Check the contents of extfile.cnf.  Based on that article, there should only be 2 lines in it, containing `subjectAltName = DNS:...` and `extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth`.  IMO, that first command should have contained only a single greater-than (`>`) symbol to create the extfile.cnf; not append to it (with double >> symbols).

Comment: @leeharvey1 thanks, it seems to have been a combination of 2 things. 
1st was that it was splitting it into more than 2 lines, so I just edited the file and 2nd is that I had to change the file to UTF-8. Then all was good.

Comment: leeharvey1thanks for that, it keeps appending for the double >> symbol.

GeneSmith thanks for telling us this too, I changed it to UTF-8 and it generates 2 lines, which should be only 1, I edited it too using notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

**Please change your extfile.cnf file with**

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.domain.com
IP.1 = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Hopefully will work for you

Comment: I was having the same problem and, make sure that you extfile.conf is in ANSI encoding format. It solves the problem for me.